# How to create a share link with a preview for a website made with streamlit?

Tags: apache, preview, streamlit

I built a website using Streamlit as "frontend": whoever connects to `example.com` goes to the port 8501 of the Apache server where my Streamlit app is exposed.

My problem is the following:
when I share the link `example.com` on social media or Whatsapp I get an ugly link, with just the word ***Streamlit*** as preview.

Is there a way to customize the preview with an image and a short description of the site?

I saw this but it was not helpful because my site is not hosted on Streamlit cloud
https://docs.streamlit.io/streamlit-cloud/get-started/share-your-app/share-previews

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a tunnel for external users to access your local server (APACHE or NGINX). You can either use ngrok or Cloudfare for it.

[Cloudfare Expose Port Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ey4u7OUAF3c)

However, for a more practical purpose of having it on most of the times for your prospective users to try out without significant risks of attacks on your local system, I would advice sign up on either Streamlit Sharing or HuggingFace Spaces using your GitHub account and simply use their GUI (select repo, select branch, click deploy) for the same purpose!